# SQL - How to select row by compare date from 2 table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 table like that:

**Table1:**

```
ID |    COMPANY_NAME  | Rank |  FIRST_REGIST_DATE

  1           A           1          2017-09-01
  2           B           2          2017-09-05
```

**Table 2:**

```
 ID | COMPANY_NAME    | RANK  |   FIRST_REGIST_DATE
 1           A            3          2017-09-03
 2           C            4          2017-09-04
```

I need to SELECT company with the data FIRST_REGIST_DATE and RANK
In case of company have 2 first regist date, we choose the earlier date and RANK **greater**
(EX: company A above will have first date: 2017-09-01)

The Expect result will like that:
Company A - Rank 3 - Date:2017-09-01

Please have me to SELECT in that case

Comment: Whats your expected result?

Comment: Sorry guy, I have updated the answer.

Comment: What takes preference `FIRST_REGIST_DATE` or `RANK`? ie. Company B & C have the same ID. B has a later date but higher rank than C, What do you expect to see first?

Comment: I don't understand the comment correctly, But in expect result, I was define for company A: Rank greater and Date earlier.  company B and C may be on make sence

Comment: You expect to see Company A first, no problem. Which company will be second on your list? B OR C??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technically answers the question but avoids the elephant in the room (which ID takes preference?). As both tables have ID's that may overlap ({B,C} have an ID of 2) rules need to be defined as to which ID takes preference what will the other table ID's be renamed to.

```
    Select COMPANY_NAME
           ,MIN(FIRST_REGIST_DATE) as REGIST_DATE
    from (
            SELECT *
            FROM #table1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM #table2 
    ) t3
    Group by COMPANY_NAME
```

OP dont change your question (by adding RANK) after the question has been answered. 
For your changes: kindly contributed by @toha

```
    Select COMPANY_NAME
          ,MIN(FIRST_REGIST_DATE) as REGIST_DATE 
          ,MAX(RANK ) as RANK 
    from ( SELECT * 
           FROM #table1 
             UNION ALL 
           SELECT * 
           FROM #table2 ) t3 
    Group by COMPANY_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that ID as different, I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why is there a distinct in the select statement, since you have grouped by company_name you are going to get a single record for each company and the distinct is not required.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. But it seem to be my mistake, I was missed case in the question. I have just add expect result. Sorry for convinence :(

Comment: I was looking at using a `distinct` and `Order by` instead of a `MIN()` but left both in. It has now been edited

Comment: RANK greater is missed

Comment: @toha, OP changed the question and added RANK after the answers were posted

Comment: Maybe it should be :  Select COMPANY_NAME
           ,MIN(FIRST_REGIST_DATE) as REGIST_DATE
, MAX(RANK ) as RANK   from (
            SELECT *
            FROM #table1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM #table2 
    ) t3
    Group by COMPANY_NAME

Comment: No prob. @user3240704

Comment: @user3240704, toha: Thank you so much, I have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you have two tables with data containing company details and first registration date and you want to show the row with the earliest first registration date. The following query will help you.

```
SELECT company_name, MIN(fisrt_regist_date)
(
SELECT company_name, fisrt_regist_date
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT company_name, fisrt_regist_date
FROM table2
) tab1
FROM tab1
GROUP BY company_name
```

The above query will combine the results of the first table and the second table and then show you the details of the company along with the oldest registration date.

Comment: you can use UNION instead of UNION ALL as you don't need all the available records to preform this operation and the answer is correct as per my understanding as well.

Comment: Perfect solution unless company B is also in Table2 (where it looks at though it would be assigned an ID other than '2'), in which case there will be a duplication due to the companies having multiple ID's.

Comment: @Suraz UNION is costly in terms of performance compared to UNION ALL.

Comment: @phonetic_man, yeah right, it's all based on data if you are sure data on the tables are unique, then UNION ALL is better but if you are not sure or much duplicate data exist then better to use UNION only if when your requirement needs distinct data.